# Best practise for Update form in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

i'm creating my first app in angular2 and am facing a dilemma when it came to my first **Entity Update Form using formBuilder**.
I made a working form but still not sure it fits the best practises.

my object comes from a mongoDb collection. An object expense with two simple text properties.

here's what i do in the controller.

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';

import {RouteParams} from 'angular2/router';

import {Expenses} from 'collections/expenses';

import {RouterLink} from 'angular2/router';

import {Router} from 'angular2/router';

import {FormBuilder, Control, ControlGroup, Validators} from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'expense-details'
})
@View({
    templateUrl: '/client/expense-details/expense-details.html',
    directives: [RouterLink]
})
export class ExpenseDetails {
    expenseForm:ControlGroup;
    expenseId;


    constructor(params: RouteParams, private router: Router) {
        this.expenseId= params.get('expenseId');
        var expense = Expenses.findOne(this.expenseId);

        var fb = new FormBuilder();
        this.expenseForm = fb.group({
            label:[expense.label, Validators.required],
            description:[expense.description]
        })
    }

    saveExpense(expense){
        console.log(this.expenseForm.valid);
        console.log(expense);
        if(this.expenseForm.valid){
            Expenses.update(this.expenseId, {
                $set:{
                    label:expense.label,
                    description:expense.description
                }
            })
            this.router.navigate(['ExpensesList']);
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the right behaviour ?

Comment: which behavior do you mean?

Comment: what you want to ask which behaviour ? apart from your question, i have found one mistake in your code you are missing to import FORM_DIRECTIVES in the directive list.

Comment: Behaviour is a translation mistake, i meant to say: is this the proper way to create an update form ?

Answer (score 1):

You are saving the expense in a variable that only the constructor knows about, you should set it as a component property so you can access it in the save method.

As for best practices, its just a common practice to name private properties with an initial _, like private _router: Router, just so you can distinguish them easy.

Also I haven't seen the `@View` anymore since beta, they allways use templateUrl, directives and all those properties in the `@Component` tag in all official examples.

You also need to bind the properties of your exposed "expense" object in the form using ngModel.

I don't know if this is the kind of input you were hoping for, I hope it helps.

Comment: i finally did use the expense as a component property.Looks more convenient now. Thx Langley.